# Infralution.Localization ASP.Net 2007 - Localize Enum

Tags: asp.net, enums, localization

I read this topic new  because there is not new solution for enum localization.This solution topic comes from 2007.In this library they use System.Resources.ResourceManager but I would like to work with global or local source.

The only const is :

```
 public LocalizedEnumConverter(Type type, ResourceManager resourceManager)
        : base(type, resourceManager)
    {
    }
```

My enum :

```
  [TypeConverter(typeof(LocalizedEnumConverter))]
public enum Role
{
    [StringValue("User")]
    User,

    [StringValue("Administrator")]
    Administrator,
}
```

Infralution library is not like I want. **I wish like** :

```
 [Localizable]
public enum AnaRoller
{
    [StringValue("Uye")]
    Uye,

    [StringValue("Administrator")]
    Administrator,
}
 and get the localizable enum value like this 

 AnaRoller.Uye.GetLocalizabledValue() =>> return string from globalresource 
 file if has the 
 Localizable attribute  if not have it should throw exception.

 I save in global file like this =>> name =>  Anaroller_Uye  value => User
```

How can I get my wish like this ?

Comment: do you have any problem?

Comment: for me yes :) I try the above code but dont get it like I wish

Comment: then ask your question clearly....

Comment: you have right I edit now my question.

Comment: "How can I get my wish like this ?"  explain your wish...

Comment: I explain it " I wish like : " in the question